# How to keep a persistent video playing across page clicks in shopify, like Picture in Picture

Tags: shopify

I know that Shopify is not a single page application so I'm having trouble figuring out a way to keep a single video playing throughout page clicks and navigations.  The requirement is to keep the video window playing without interruption as a user navigates across from collections to product detail page.  It would occupy the same location on the page across both pages, but we don't want to have it reload the video on the new page click.  You can think of it almost as Picture in Picture.

One possibility is to have the entire site in an iframe with the video playing in the parent frame and the shopify site in the iframe - but that seems like that's problem-filled, especially since navigation would exist in the parent frame.

Answer (score 0):

Make your theme a SPA and your problems disappear. With Shopify you can render no layout, and just pure JSON data for things of interest.

Means you have to work, but you can build in your requirement of a picture in picture. Otherwise you are SOL.